# Traffic to and from mongodb using SSL is still visible in wireshark in plaintext

Tags: windows, ssl, mongodb, wireshark

> EDIT: There was nothing wrong. I was an idiot. The below settings are
>   correct.

I've set up an instance of mongodb (3.4) on windows, configured like this:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  ssl:
      mode: preferSSL
      PEMKeyFile: C:\...\mongodb.pem
      CAFile: C:\...\mongodb.ca
      allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true
```

The certificate is a CA-signed certificate issued for a specific domain and a wildcard subdomain.

I can then connect to the database from my local machine using a simple C# program that has the following connection string:

```
mongodb://user:password@hostname?ssl=true
```

and it works fine. The client is not using a certificate.

I've fiddled with the parameters and it really seems like it really is connecting using SSL:

- If I switch to `mode:requireSSL` and set `ssl=false` in the connection string, I cannot connect, which is expected
- If I connect to a domain that is not included in the certificate, I get `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`, which is also expected
- The only errors/warnings I see in the mongo log is `no SSL certificate provided by peer` - which is expected; the client is not using a certificate, thats why I've configured `allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true`

**However**, when I look at the traffic using Wireshark, I can inspect all the packets and read the data being sent to and from the server in plaintext. There is no SSL/TLS layer in the packet details pane, just Ethernet, IP, TCP and then Mongo Wire protocol.

*My question is*: is this expected? Shouldn't the traffic be encrypted, and thus unreadable in Wireshark?

Comment: Nevermind, turns out I'm an idiot and can't read Wireshark logs correctly. The traffic was indeed encrypted.

Comment: There isn't any "idiot". Just mistakes. Perhaps you were a bit tired and didn't see well :).